# How do I recieve/get the audio/video data from a youtube video?

Tags: java, youtube

I've long time wanting to know how I can get the audio data or whole video data from a youtube video. I did what any reasonable person would do, I googled it.

Sadly I didn't find any good answers. Mostly of what I was suggested was to get the data out of download links provided by: http://www.youtube.com/get_video.php?video_id={VideoKey}

However, it doesn't work anymore. Comments from forum sections etc, also suggest other people facing the same problem as I. So from that I take the conclusion that this information is out of date. But there must be a way since other websites and browser addons like, KeepVid.com or YoutubeInMp3.com still works.

So my question is simple. How do I recieve/get the audio/video data from a youtube video? In a link perhaps?

Comment: You realized that SO provides a button to accept answers to your previous questions?

Comment: You can not do what you want without violating Youtube Terms Of Service: http://www.youtube.com/t/terms

Comment: youtube-dl : https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who better to ask, other than google themselves https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java

Example: The following example demonstrates how to retrieve a standard feed and print information about the videos in that feed.

```
String feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed";
VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
printVideoFeed(videoFeed, true);
```

Comment: That will give you information about the feed, not the audio/video data itself.